# Deployment Issue In Symfony2 - Can't Find Registered Bundles?

Tags: deployment, symfony

I'm transferring my project from the laptop to a test/production server. I'm copying the files to the server via FTP. So far, I can access the /web/config.php file and /web/app_dev.php files alright.

However, when I go to try and load a page it comes up with the following error:

> ReflectionException: Class Knp\Menu\ItemInterface does not exist

In the error report, all the files look to be held in the following root directory:

> /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/

On the laptop however, the root directory was www:

> C:\wamp\www

Everything on the test server is held in the httpdocs folder. What do I need to do to fix this error?

Cheers

EDIT:
I have moved everything in to a www folder, held within httpdocs folder. It's completely broken doing that, no pages will load.

Comment: Do you have access to any error logs?

Comment: I haven't unfortunately. I haven't had chance to look at this error until today, I will no doubt find out what's wrong with it today.

Comment: First step would be to make sure the file holding the `ItemInterface` was actually transferred.

Comment: It had transferred. I have the explanation in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occured from an incorrectly configured .htaccess file on the development server.

During the configuration, the root directory wasn't changed to /web. Once this was changed however, the plugin worked.